# Where are these line breaks coming from?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on simplifying the design of my WordPress log. All I want for the metadata that appears above a post or a post's title is it to appear in a single, fairly nondescript line.

The pseudo-code would look like this:

```
$date $category $edit
```

What it actually looks like is here: http://johnlaudun.org/20120828-isaac-at-9pm/

The CSS for this line is:

```
.entry-meta {
    font-family: "Avenir Next Condensed", "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    font-size: .75em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.entry-meta p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.entry-meta a {text-decoration: none;}
.entry-meta .date {color: #000;}
.cat-links a {color: #436EEE;}
.edit-link a {color: orange;}
```

And the PHP is:

```
<div class="entry-meta">

<p>             
    <?php if ( ! is_page() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_time( 'Y M d' ); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?> &nbsp;

    <span class="cat-links">
    <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span>

    <span class="edit-link">
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'chunk' ) ); ?></span>

</p>
</div>
```

It generates the following output to a browser:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
        <p>

                        <a href="http://johnlaudun.org/20120828-isaac-at-9pm/">
            2012 Aug 28</a>
             &nbsp;

            <span class="cat-links">
            <a href="http://johnlaudun.org/category/status-2/" title="View all posts in status" rel="category tag">status</a></span>

            <span class="edit-link">
            <a class="post-edit-link" href="http://johnlaudun.org/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post=5052&amp;action=edit" title="Edit Post">Edit</a></span>

        </p>
    </div>
```

What am I missing that is inserting some sort of line break into what should be, from my point of view, a fairly simply output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at style.css, line 191 :

```
.cat-links, .tag-links {
  display: block;
}
```

Try with : `display: inline;`

Comment: I must have scrolled past that two dozen times. I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: You should use dev tools and save your time

Comment: I don't know that I follow what you mean by `dev tools`. What do you advise?

Comment: You can try Firebug with firefox, or built-in dev tools with chrome... etc

Comment: I was using Safari's source viewer, but not the Web Inspector, which would have done the trick. Thanks for pointing that out!